# Unexpected true value returned from function comparing getComputedStyle().width values

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
const wider_than = (el1, el2) => getComputedStyle(el1).width > getComputedStyle(el2).width;
```

I am using it to control the innerhtml value of a nested div. If the inner div is wider than the outter div i want the inner div to set its text to "error". Else I want to set it to a user defined value.

But the function is returning true at unexpected times. Using the following logs

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(display_text).width);
console.log(getComputedStyle(display).width);
console.log(wider_than(display_text, display));
console.log(getComputedStyle(display_text).width > getComputedStyle(display).width);
```

and updating the value of the display_text innerHTML character by character, it runs normally for the first character but then breaks for the second character. Here is the outputs from the logs

```
53.3958px
639px
false
false
80.0625px
639px
true
true
```

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: You are comparing *strings*. Lexicographically `"8"` is "more" than `"6"`, hence the result. You want to `parseFloat` those values into numbers before comparing

Comment: Should have known from the px in the output. Thanks very much.

Comment: @isherwood I was just heading to bed, so I didn't have the time to post a full answer. I thought somebody would by now but since there was nothing, I did post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('"b" > "a"       :', "b" > "a");//"b" comes after "a"
console.log('"bun" > "abbot" :', "bun" > "abbot");//"b" comes after "a" regardless of word length

console.log('"2" > "1"       :', "2" > "1");
console.log('"2" > "100"     :', "2" > "100");
```

There is a good reason for strings to not be sorted like numbers - imagine you have a playlist and are trying to sort song titles, *"7"* by Arctic Monkeys should come after *"19th Nervous Breakdown"* by the Rolling Stones.

The [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) global function is tailored to extracting numbers from strings that start with them. So it's ideal for size values like "53.3958px"

```js
const size1 = "53.3958px";
const size2 = "639px";
const size3 = "80.0625px";

console.log(`${size1} > ${size2} compared as strings:`, size1 > size2);
console.log(`${size1} > ${size2} compared as numbers:`, parseFloat(size1) > parseFloat(size2));

console.log(`${size3} > ${size2} compared as strings:`, size3 > size2);
console.log(`${size3} > ${size2} compared as numbers:`, parseFloat(size3) > parseFloat(size2));
```